# should I do immutable sequence algorithm on redux container?

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I am new to react/redux. I am using container pattern with redux store (which store immutablejs objects like Map/Set...).

As I know, React component has a method called shouldComponentUpdate for props shadow comparison. Immutable will help much on this calculation. So My question is should I do sequence algorithm in redux container like below?

```
export default connect(
  (state) => ({
      data: state.getIn(['data', 'map'])
        .filter((obj, key) => state.getIn(['user', 'selectedDataSet']).has(key))
        .toSet(),
    }),
)(MyComponent);
```

or is it better to put this logic in componentWillReceiveProps()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep this functionality in your mapStateToPropsFunction (the first parameter to the connect for those who don't know). I like to keep props passed to my components as limited as possible. i.e I only send in props that will be needed by the component or it's children. This way your component doesn't have to know how to handle extra props or have any special logic.

Another benefit to keeping the logic in mapStateToProps is that your component could extend PureComponent (`class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent`) to get a free shouldComponentUpdate with shallow prop checking!

That being said, I am sure there are other reasons you might want to keep this in the child component.

Edit: On ImmutableJS

React pairs very well with Immutable JS. An `===` comparison is still all that is needed to determine if a deeply nested object has changed (the rule that any changes create an entirely new object make this possible).

You should pass everything that the react component needs in order to render. If the component depends a list for example, pass the whole list into the component and then filter it out before rendering.

In your example:

```
render() {
    const data = dataProp
        .filter((obj, key) => state.getIn(['user', 'selectedDataSet']).has(key))
        .toSet()

    return (
        <div>{data}</div>
    );
}
```

This assumes your connect looks something like this (note that this may not be 100% correct syntax).

```
export default connect(
  (state) => ({
      dataProp: state.getIn(['data', 'map'])
    }),
)(MyComponent);
```

Comment: As I tried before, I found that map / filter like function will generate a new object instead of using the same one. please see below. ```const list = Immutable.List([1,2,3]);``` when we do this checking it will show false instead of true as below. ```list.map(data => data * 2) === list.map(data => data * 2)``` this will make the shouldComponentUpdate make a should update decision.

Comment: This is exactly what makes Immutable so great! Any data that is changed in the object creates an entirely new object. This way if a change occurs at a deep level in an object, you can still use simple comparison (`===`) to check if a component should be updated. Let me add a quick update to my post.

Comment: I think what we should do is passing the hold list of immutable from container to component to get the free shadow compare on shouldComponentUpdate.

Comment: I agree. I personally think that is one great way of using ImmutableJS to squeeze out performance with React.

Comment: I have a new question for this topic. one of the usage of container is to decouple the component from data. So that component can be easy to be reuse. The problem I found is, if we do many seq algorithm in component rather than in container, it makes the container depend much more on the structure of the store. It will after the reusability.